# How to display image on posts in WordPress grid

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [this theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/pinbin) for developing a website in WordPress.

I added image with a post using the media option in the theme. But this image is not getting displayed in the grid structure as shown in the original theme.

After the post is added it only has text contents in the grid and when I open each post I’m able to see the image.

How can the image be displayed on the post?

[image: This is how i get the page even after uploading the picture]

Comment: Try adding image in a `featured image` of the posts.

Comment: @Rikesh where can i find that option ?

Comment: On post edit page, right side of it.